# Unity3d- crossdomain.xml policy file not found when trying to register to a database server

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, crossdomain.xml

I am having this problem for about two days now and I tried all the solutions that I could find online, but still no luck.
what's happening is that in my game, when I press a specific button I am supposed to register to a private database server of mine that is hosted in azure.
when running the build on IOS or Android I have no problem with registering, but in the Unity web player build I get a "Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found" error, even though I  made sure that the file is located in the root of my server and is formatted ASCII, as written in the Unity sandbox guide.
I am only using the WWW class and no socket.
When I try registering from my localhost and from the unity editor i have no problems, but **only when i upload the html file to an online host, such as dropbox,** and access it through a URL the problem occurs.

if anyone can help me find the problem it would be amazing. I have finished my game and it works perfectly on all platforms except the web player, so it is the only thing that is holdin me back. thanks allot

Answer (score 0):

In the docs on [unity webplayer sandbox](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SecuritySandbox.html) it gives you the reason for this. A quick fix is to add a file accesable on `http://yourdomain/crossdomain.xml` with the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```